Trying to find a movie, European, Private Detective, Sex Slavery maybe
I watched this movie a while ago on sbs, it is european, about a male detective. Maybe released 2000-2010.
At the beginning he pretends to be a cop to arrests this boy, he steals hash from him, the hash the called "Black Afghan". He goes back somewhere to smoke it with this other guy.
He goes to this other city for most of the movie, I think in the end the crime doesn't get resolved he just leaves the city maybe??
There are these big group showers at some point, I think it is like a homeless shelter situation. At some point the protagonist and a girl get locked in the shower and someone turns it on very hot, they are like struggling in the shower for a good while, putting up their coats against the shower head to shelter themselves from the water.
So I think there is some kind of sex trafficking. There is a (opera?) singer client that wants a girl to pee into his mouth. There is something mentioned about them getting checks for std's and stuff.
There might be government involved?
Any clues?

This reminds me to a large degree of the excellent Austrian black-humoured crime movie Silentium, the second of three movies about hobby detective Simon Brenner based on the books by Wolf Haas:

A man who accused a catholic bishop of abusing him when he was a child
  dies in the Austrian city Salzburg. Everyone except his widow and the
  eccentrical detective Simon Brenner keeps silent and believes that the
  man killed himself.

I remember many of your mentioned plot points. The showers where he (and the girl he wants to protect) is about to be effectively cooked, the sex trafficking plot, and the opera singer (the story is set against the background of the Salzburg Festival) wanting a girl to pee into his mouth.
I don't quite remember how it ends, but the crime not getting resolved explicitly would fit to the rather inconclusive feeling I tend to remember from those movies.
